# function to count all invoices for a specific customer between dates

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to Create a function to count all invoices for a specific customer     on or after a specific date. Can anyone check if my function is right or a better way to do this.

```
create or replace function count_invoice
(cus in number, d in date)
return number
as
num number;
begin

select count(inv_number) into num from invoice 
where cus_code = cus and inv_date > d;

return num;
end;
/
```

Comment: Looks ok, did you try it?

Answer (score 1):

It mostly works, as long as (A) `INV_NUMBER` is the primary key in the `INVOICE` table and (B) that `CUS_CODE` is a `NUMBER` column in that table.  (I'm assuming `INV_DATE` is a `DATE` column...)

The only thing clearly wrong that I see is you want `inv_date >= d`, not `inv_date > d`, based on the requirements you wrote.